# Is there a non-technical gender-neutral term for child above the age where a person is no longer considered a child?

Tags: synonyms, kinship-terms, gender-neutral

A person is their parent's child always, but past an arbitrary age, it's no longer appropriate to call them a "child".

I'm familiar with the term "Offspring", but that sounds technical, is there a more conversational synonym?

Comment: Please provide an example sentence where this term would be used.

Comment: Child is gender neutral, non-technical, and means a son or a daughter of any age. You don't stop being somebody's child when you reach thirty. Although son/daughter seems more dignified for anyone over 50.

Comment: *Adult child* works in the neutral sense, but the same term is also used in at least a couple of derogatory senses.

Comment: I agree with @Mari-LouA about the gender-specific forms. *X & Sons* is one formula for family-business names, though *X & Daughters* is rare.

Answer (score 0):

The legal term is "issue".  This may be more technical than you want, but it is age-invariant and gender-neutral.

Comment: As you say, *issue* is age invariant.  OP asks for a word to refer to one’s grown children.

Comment: fair enough.  At first read I had thought he/she was not necessarily looking for a conversational term.  It is, indeed, what lawyers would use which is both age- and gender-neutral.  But in speaking, 'grown children', 'adult children', or 'sons and daughters' seems to be the only real choices.